# Nullary lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python interpreter, I can define a function to be `1` but not `print(1)`

```
>>> lambda: 1
<function <lambda> at 0x023D03F0>
>>> lambda: print(1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lambda: print(1)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because (at least in traditional Python 2), `print` is not a function, it's a statement - so it doesn't make sense in the body of a lambda.

In Python 3, or in Python 2 with the `print_function` option enabled, `print` is a function, and it does work in a lambda:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> lambda: print(1)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f69ab049578>
>>>
```